# Birkat Habanim (Blessing of the sons) on Shabbat Yom Tov, Shabbat Rosh Hashana and Shabbat Yom Kippur

Tags: shabbat, blessing, yom-kippur, yom-tov, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Those who bless their sons in Birkat Habanim, every Sabbath evening when returning from synagogue. Should the father bless his sons on Shabbat on that falls on Yom Tov falls? and how will he behave regarding Shabbat Rosh Hashanah? And what about Shabbat Yom Kippur? Because on Yom Kippur, there is the blessing of the sons before going to the synagogue after lighting the candles? Regarding Yom Tov - I heard (and I don't know if it is right) that since, according to some customs, Shalom Aleichem is not said on Shabbat Yom Tov, then the angels do not join back from the synagogue and therefore do not bless the sons?